# 1050 Cannot assign to a non-reference value as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having some trouble with the error `"1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value."` I'm still fairly new to coding, and so being unable to fix this error is frustrating, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var PracticeDummyHealth:int=50
var PlayerAttack:int=20;

public function PlayerAttackFunction(){
    if(PracticeDummyHealth>0){
        PracticeDummyHealth-PlayerAttack=PracticeDummyHealth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An grammar construct which is *not* a Property/Variable name is on the *left* of the `=` assignment operator:

```
// expression                   = expression
PracticeDummyHealth-PlayerAttack=PracticeDummyHealth;
// which makes as much sense to ActionScript as .. it's not an equation solver :)
// 100 - 50 = 100
```

Compare with this valid code:

```
// variable         = new_value
PracticeDummyHealth = PracticeDummyHealth - PlayerAttack;
// or
PracticeDummyHealth -= PlayerAttack;
```

Note that a "reference" (read: Property/Variable name) appears on the *left* of the `=` (or compound `-=`) in both of these cases. This terminology comes from the specification which deals with l-values and it is slightly unfortunate it doesn't yield a nicer error message here.